# Jquery Ui Sortable: how to detect each fired event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

**This is the situation:**

I have a simple app that use Jquery Ui Sortable ( http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets ) for drag and drop items between three different columns.

The three columns names are:

- Todo
- Work in progress
- Done

When I move items from the first two columns in the third I need to change the class of item (bootstrap panel) and make it green (panel-success).

To each column i assign a value yes/no to identify the Done column:

```
<?
    $column_done = 'no';
    if ($value_board_column['name'] == 'Done') 
    {
        $column_done = 'yes';
    }
?>

<div class="sorted" data-board_done="<?= $column_done ?>">
```

In the UPDATE event I alert the value of board-done:

```
update: function(event, ui) 
{
    var board_done = $(this).data('board_done');
    alert( 'Board_done: ' + board_done );
}
```

**This is the key point:**

The UPDATE event is fired two times, the two times that the DOM changes, precisely when the item is removed from one column and inserted in another.

So the alert appear two times.
The first time i see the value referred to the original column, the second time the value referred to the second column.

For example if a move one item from TODO to DONE, in the alert i see: 'no' and then 'yes'.

**This is the question:**

Since I only need the second value, how can I detect it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be using the [receive()](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event.

```
receive: function(event, ui) 
{
    var board_done = $(this).data('board_done');
    alert( 'Board_done: ' + board_done );
}
```